# Integration and null function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, definite-integrals, riemann-integration

Let $ f: [a, b] \rightarrow {\mathbb {R}} $ be continuous and such that $$ \int_ {a} ^ {b} {f (x) g (x) dx} = 0 $$ for all $ g: [a, b] \rightarrow {\mathbb {R}} $ continuous with $ g (a) = g (b) = 0 $. Show that $ f $ is null in $ [a, b] $.

Test (Attempt): Let's see that $ f $ is null, that is, $ f (x) = 0 $, for every $ x \in [a, b]$. By absurdity. Let $c\in [a, b]$ be such that $ f (c) \neq 0 $. Suppose that $ f (c)> 0 $. Since $ f $ is continuous in $ [a, b] $, then for $ \epsilon = \frac {f (c)} {2}> 0 $, there exists $ \delta> 0 $ such that if $ x \in [a, b] \cap {(c- \delta, c + \delta)} $, then $ f (x)> 0 $.

Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: I'd try proof by contradiction. In any case, this would probably be a more interesting question if your thoughts were edited into it. What did you think of trying, what did you actually try, how exactly made this question so difficult? Writing this out might also help you think further about the question.

Comment: @DavidK I will try to write what I have. It is not much...

Comment: @DavidK I don't know what else to say. Can you help me?

Comment: For a start see what happens if $g(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: @YadatiKiran I would have problems with the condition $ g (a) = g (b) = 0 $, so I don't know if $ f $ verifies that, right?

Comment: @Darkmaster : $f$ is given to be a continuous function, so $g$ can be $f$. Although you will have to show $f\equiv0$ fot when $f(a)>0$ and $f(b)>0$. This might help [https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1723551/if-int-01fxgxdx-0-for-all-g-such-that-g0-g1-0-then-f-0?rq=1]. In your attempt, see i you can contradict the continuity of $f$.

Comment: See similar question: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2123435/72031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose then that

$\exists y \in (a, b), \; f(y) \ne 0; \tag 1$

replacing $f(x)$ with $-f(x)$ if necessary, we may assume that

$f(y) > 0; \tag 2$

the continuity of $f(x)$ then allows us to assert the existence of some real

$\epsilon > 0 \tag 3$

such that

$x \in [y - \epsilon, y + \epsilon] \subset (a, b) \Longrightarrow f(x) \ge \dfrac{f(y)}{2}; \tag 4$

we may now define a function

$g:[a, b] \to \Bbb R \tag 5$

as follows:

$x \in [a, y - \epsilon], \; g(x) = 0, \tag 6$

$x \in [y - \epsilon, y], \; g(x) = \dfrac{f(y)}{2}(x - (y - \epsilon)), \tag 7$

$x \in [y, y + \epsilon], \; g(x) = \dfrac{f(y)}{2}((y + \epsilon) - x), \tag 8$

$x \in [y + \epsilon, b], \; g(x) = 0;\tag 9$

then $g(x)$ is easily seen to be a continuous function on $[a,b]$ with

$g(a) = g(b) = 0; \tag{10}$

the graph of $g(x)$ is flat and fixed at $0$ for $x \in [a, y - \epsilon] \cup [y + \epsilon, b]$ and exhibits a positive triangular "spike" of height $\epsilon f(y)/2$ centered at $y$ with base $[y - \epsilon, y + \epsilon]$; it follows then that

$x \in [a, y - \epsilon] \cup [y + \epsilon, b] \Longrightarrow f(x)g(x) = 0, \tag{11}$

$x \in [y - \epsilon, y] \Longrightarrow f(x)g(x) \ge \dfrac{(f(y))^2}{4}(x - (y - \epsilon)), \tag{12}$

$x \in [y, y + \epsilon] \Longrightarrow f(x)g(x) \ge  \dfrac{(f(y))^2}{4}((y + \epsilon) - x); \tag{13}$

it is easy to see that $f(x)g(x) \ge 0$ is a continuous function on $[a,b]$ and that

$x \in (y - \epsilon, y + \epsilon) \Longrightarrow f(x)g(x) > 0, \; x \notin (y - \epsilon, y + \epsilon) \Longrightarrow f(x)g(x) = 0; \tag{14}$

it follows then that

$\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x)g(x) \; dx > 0, \tag{15}$

which contradicts our hypothesis that

$\displaystyle \int_a^b f(x) g(x) \; dx = 0; \tag{16}$

we are thus forced to conclude that

$f(x) = 0, \; \forall x \in [a, b]. \tag{17}$

$OE\Delta$.

Comment: Since $ f $ and $ g $ with continuous, then $ fg $ is continuous, right?

Comment: @Darkmaster: yes basic theory

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is continuous it is enough to show $\int_a^b f(t)^2 dt=0$. Let $\vert f(t)\vert\leq M$ for all $a\leq t\leq b$ and let $\varepsilon<(b-a)/2$. Then define $g=g_\varepsilon$ by 
$g(t):= f(a+\varepsilon) (t-a)/\varepsilon\text{ if } a\leq t<a+\varepsilon$,
$g(t)
:=f(t)\text{ if } a+\varepsilon\leq t\leq b-\varepsilon$ and
$g(t):=f(b-\varepsilon)(b-t)/\varepsilon\text{ if } b-\varepsilon<t\leq b$. Then by assumption $\int_{a+\varepsilon}^{b-\varepsilon} f(t)^2 dt+\int_a^{a+\varepsilon}f(t)g(t)dt+\int_{b-\varepsilon}^b f(t)g(t)dt=0$. This implies that 
$\int_{a+\varepsilon}^{b-\varepsilon} f(t)^2 dt\leq\int_a^{a+\varepsilon}\vert f(t)g(t)\vert dt+\int_{b-\varepsilon}^b \vert f(t)g(t)\vert dt$. The integral in the RHS may be estimated by $K\varepsilon$ with $K$ depending in $M$ only. So with $\varepsilon\to0$ you get 
$\int_{a}^{b
} f(t)^2 dt\leq0$.

*Edit* I
just realized that there is a similar question with good answers here:
[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1723551/if-int-01fxgxdx-0-for-all-g-such-that-g0-g1-0-then-f-0?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Notice that in the question the test functions $g$ must satisfy $g(0)=g(1)=0$, whereas $f$ need not.

Comment: I noticed this and I believe that the answers took this into account.